# Spotting mechanics in console

Tags: xbox-360, world-of-tanks

I read this: http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Battle_Mechanics#Radio_Range

In Xbox 360 edition you can see allies always, but there it says that you can only see them when in range. I think in console you can see the enemies whenever an ally detects it, no matter the distance, but I can't be sure.

So how spotting mechanics work on the console?

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki entry is correct. Personally, I have experienced allies disappearing from the map quite a few times when I am a long way from them. This happens on bigger maps quite often but is nearly impossible to achieve on smaller maps as allies' radio range will cover nearly anything.

Comment: plus in the beginning tiers, all maps are rather small.